# Set the phonegap application to cover 100% of screen at all orientations

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, cordova

I noticed when I ran the phonegap application to my 8.9 tablet that whenever I do a horizontal screen, the application does not cover the entire screen. there's a white space at the bottom and it's ugly.

I'm using phonegap + jquerymobile with themes.

Comment: Did you get this to work, and if so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you are a meta tag with a viewport? Something like this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,height=device-height,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1">
```

Comment: Did not find this to work.  Seems as though there's another issue going on.